# PHP: class properties become linked against my will

Tags: php

I'm losing my mind over this. I've deconstructed my class down to the basics and it's still happening.
So this class:

```
class Insanity
{
    protected $simon;
    protected $garfunkel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->simon = new stdClass();
        $this->garfunkel = new stdClass();
    }
}
```

Everything's fine and dandy.
If I do `$this->simon->name = 'paul';` and `$this->garfunkel->name = 'art';` they are both happy seperate vars.

Until I do `$this->simon = $this->garfunkel;`

From this point onward they become linked/referenced or whatever,
 so when I do `$simon->name = 'homer';`, it becomes the name of both.

And even if I do `$this->simon->whatTheF = 'uck';` then `$garfunkel` ends up with that property too, although a quick `var_dump()` claims the two variables are still seperate (by name).

Anybody got an idea why?

Comment: Do you mean `$this->simon = stdClass();`? etc?

Comment: Can you provide information for your stdClass-function? or should it be `new stdClass`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the syntax was very wrong. Fixed it.

Comment: I totally like how you named your stuff ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$simon` and `$garfunkel` do not contain the object itself. They are just *references* to the object. You could also call them *pointer*. If you do `$simon = $garfunkel`, you will just copy this reference and therefore `$simon` will point at the exact same object as `$garfunkel` does.

If you want to copy the object itself, PHP offers you the `clone` keyword for that:

```
$simon = clone $garfunkel;
```

Comment: Ok. That's it. I never knew that. And I could swear I've done similar things in the past without problems (i.e. without me recognizing then ... who knows what havoc I have wrecked ...) THANK YOU

Comment: Note that this only applies to objects. Other types do not show this behavior by default. But you CAN have references for other types as well if you say so explicitely. `$foo =& $bar;` will make `$foo` contain a reference to whatever `$bar` contains. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php for more information.